# Impact RenderTransformOrigin to MatrixTransform in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, rendering, affinetransform

I use `MatrixTransform` for transform my element:

```
 element.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform() 
                           { Matrix = new Matrix(a, b, c, d, e, f) };
```

I don't understand how rendering of my `element` with `MatrixTransform` depends from `element.RenderTransformOrigin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RenderTransformOrigin determines the transfer of the coordinate system before MatrixTransform